# Low voltage on raspberry pi?

Tags: power, voltage

I have an old charger from my RP3 using in RP4 with micro-usb -> usb-C cap on it. I have a feeling that my Pi has not enough power- When I start Pi with `fan` connected to pins, it makes sounds like it tries to speed up rotations of the fan but has not enough power for it.
I tried to get `voltage` value of the `pi's core` And have this numbers is it normal?

```bsh
>>> for id in core sdram_c sdram_i sdram_p ; do echo -e "$id:\t$(vcgencmd measure_volts $id)" ; done

core:   volt=0.8625V
sdram_c:    volt=1.1000V
sdram_i:    volt=1.1000V
sdram_p:    volt=1.1000V

// after connecting fan
>>>pi@raspberrypi:~ $ for id in core sdram_c sdram_i sdram_p ; do echo -e "$id:\t$(vcgencmd measure_volts $id)" ; done

core:   volt=0.8350V
sdram_c:    volt=1.1000V
sdram_i:    volt=1.1000V
sdram_p:    volt=1.1000V
```

BTW. It doesn't make that sound after RP is booted and `warm-up`

Comment: Core voltage is totally and utterly irrelevant. Do you have a Question?

Comment: How could I find if the voltage is sufficient?

Comment: If the voltage is insufficient you would see the lightning bolt symbol on screen.

Comment: @CoderMike: There is no "lightning bolt" for the "Lite" version of the OS, nor is there a lightning bolt for those running "headless" for any OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Is My Raspberry Pi Getting Enough Voltage?

#### Solution 1: Get an inline USB meter:

Rather than [*tilting at windmills*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Tilting+at+Windmills), you could invest a few dollars to buy an [inline USB meter](https://www.walmart.com/search/?query=USB%20C%20Tester). Simply read the voltage on the display - they also provide a current measurement which should be useful. For about $20USD you can avoid relying upon your "feelings" to measure voltage  :)  FWIW, I have used them, and mine work very well... yet - I can't shake the feeling that my *feelings* aren't quite as sharp since I began relying on instruments :)

[image: inline USB meter]

#### Solution 2: Watch the monitor connected to your RPi

If you run your RPi connected to a monitor, the [under-voltage warning](https://www.raspberrypistarterkits.com/guide/raspberry-pi-lightning-bolt/) will be displayed in the upper right-hand corner of the monitor. It may flash intermittently, or it may remain on steadily.

#### Solution 3: Use the `vcgencmd get_throttled` command

You can use the `vcgencmd` utility from the command line (or use it in a script you write) to give you the status. This will work with or without a connected monitor. This requires a bit more effort than the first two solutions, but a potential advantage is that you may learn something. Using my RPi 3B+, it goes something like this:

```bsh
$ vcgencmd get_throttled
throttled=0x50000
```

What does that mean? In this case, `throttled=0x50000` means that my RPi 3B+ has experienced an under-voltage event, ***and*** the CPU clock has been throttled. It also means that neither of those conditions exist at the time I ran this command. I'd also like to mention that my RPi 3B+ is powered from an "official" power supply, so under-voltage events will occur even when using a supply that meets RPi's specifications.

This, and other potentially [useful information on `vcgencmd` is found here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/vcgencmd.md). Specifically, see the `get_throttled` option. *Also see Note 1 below*.

Review the table supplied in the [online doc](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/vcgencmd.md), read the explanation, and feel free to ask more questions - here, or in the discussion forums (e.g. [1](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1453992), [2](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2367))

---

#### NOTES:

1. Unfortunately, [The Organization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_Foundation) has elected not to provide much system documentation - there is no `man` page, and even `vcgencmd --help` isn't much help.

Answer (score 1):

I found this:
On all models of Raspberry Pi since the Raspberry Pi B+ (2014) except the Zero range, there is low-voltage detection circuitry that will detect if the supply voltage drops below 4.63V (+/- 5%). This will result in a warning icon being displayed on all attached displays and an entry being added to the kernel log.

It could also be your RAM. How many Gb RAM do you have?

I hope this helped

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you got a fan for the wrong voltage, or connected it to the wrong pins. Fans should be connected between 5V (or 3.3V) pins and ground, **not** to regular GPIOs. 5V is sufficient for most small fans, 3.3V is enough for some but might be insufficient for others.

If you connect a 12V fan to 5V, it is expected that it never reaches full speed.